# Are state machine states always supposed to update in the inspector Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use a enum for idle, walking, running and jumping and then a switch statement to handle all of those states.

I have idle as the main/default state and after a movement is completed, the state goes back to idle.

```
public void Update()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case PlayerState.IDLE:
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
            {
                state = PlayerState.JUMPING;
                HandleJump();                 
            }          
            break;
        case PlayerState.JUMPING:
            if (!Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                state = PlayerState.IDLE;
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void HandleJump()
{
    velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
}
```

I took out my other states just so I could show the problem. The jumping works fine and I added Debug.Log messages inside both the `IDLE` and `JUMPING` states and also in the `HandleJump` method, and debugging shows that everything works fine, and the jump itself works from inside the case. But in the inspector when I'm looking at the states with the dropdown box, the state never changes from `IDLE` -> `JUMPING`, it just stays at `IDLE` and when I press `JUMPING` during runtime, it instantly switches back to `IDLE`.

I'm not sure if that's a problem or if it's normal and I should ignore it since the code and jump movement itself actually works.

Comment: Perhaps because the moment your jump button wasnt pressed that frame it says to set the state to idle?

Comment: Yeah, maybe change the jumping case to check for grounded instead of button down (which happens for a single frame).

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yeah I tried that, I used `if (isGrounded) -> state = IDLE` inside the `JUMPING` case and even though my jump worked, there was no change in the inspector to show that I was jumping. Would I maybe need to add a bool to my jump code to show that `isJumping = true` and then use that `isJumping` bool in the case?

Comment: Edit: I fixed it. I'm just wondering, is it ok if the state in the inspector changes from jumping to idle very fast? It seems like one frame